# Get field descriptions from a parent related table in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

What would be the best way to set a gridView.DataSource for LINQ query with some foreign keys and get fields in the parent tables? Like this:

The table BOOK have a **Author_Id**, which is related to table **Author**

**class:**

```
public IQueryable<Book> ListAll()
{
    RENDBDataContext db = new RENDBDataContext();
    var result = from b in db.Books
                 orderby b.Id descending
                 select b;
}
```

**code-behind:**

```
grdBooks.DataSource = vBooks.ListAll();
grdBooks.DataBind();
```

In the ASPX page I can get to the Author name with the [asp:TemplateField], using <%Eval("Author.Name")%>

What I'm looking for is a better solution, that doesn't involve changes in the aspx page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = from b in db.Books 
             orderby b.Id descending 
             select 
             {
                 AuthorName = b.Author.Name,
                 Title      = b.Title,
                 etc        = b.etc
             };
```

Alternately, if you don't want to re-list every property you are going to use you could use:

```
var result = from b in db.Books 
             orderby b.Id descending 
             select 
             {
                 AuthorName = b.Author.Name,
                 Book       = b
             };
```

But then you'd have to write "Book.Title" in you r GridView.  However, either way, it will get all the field you need in a single SQL statement.

Comment: you missed the "new" keyword in select new {}. But I don't want to do it this way, as this would give me Anonymous types on my class-project, OR I would have to create a new class/datatype for every query like that

Comment: He also needs to figure out what he is passing back, he would have to pass back either `IQueryable<object>` or `IQueryable<dynamic>`, because he can't pass anonymous types through method boundaries as `var`.